When building a deck can I double my ledger and extend it out to a post and use it as a beam?
I am planning a deck that wraps around a corner of my house.
A logical and obvious place to put a beam happens to line up perfectly with a wall that was already going to have a ledger.
So.....why not double the ledger (sistered 2x10) but extend that doubled ledger out into empty space to sit on a post 10 feet out from the house??
So instead of a 10 foot 2x10 ledger right in line with a 10 foot 4x10 beam, can I just buy TWO 2x10 20 footers and sister them and take care of the entire 20 feet all in one shot??
Against the house this doubled 2x10 would act as a ledger and then out in empty space it would act as a beam -- I am asking if this is reasonable/acceptable?
Thanks.

Not an engineer, but it sounds reasonable to me.  How much weight this beam/ ledger needs to carry is an important factor.  I have no tables to compare a single 4x10 to a double 2x10, I'm sure there are others that do.

Usually two 2x10s are slightly stronger than a single 4x10.  Something to do with two pieces being slightly different than one piece.  This is for beams, I think it is different for posts where you want single piece.  The anchoring/mounting bolts for single 2x10 is different for two 2x10s, you have an extra 1.5 inches the bolts need to hold against shearing/bending.

You can.  20' is a long length though why not just have your double 2x10 extend only 2' onto the ledger area and use the 2' as part of the ledger.  So then you just have 12' (2)2x10 beam and a 8' single 2x10 ledger?  Do you have an eng for your deck or are you using prescriptive design?

@FreshCodemonger Yes I could just double up part of it but I like keeping things simple and I like overbuilding so the idea of the beam being continuous the entire path appeals to me.....no engineer just following the guides.....also this is below the height of my foundation so I am attaching ledger NOT to rim joist but to concrete foundation. Pressure treated 2x10 since it touches concrete and I wonder: do I attach one 2x10 to concrete first and then drill the second one through it or should I build the sister first and attach it once through the entire thing??

I did something like that for my deck but I used a pt PSL beam that sat on posts that were epoxy bolted into the concrete foundation wall.  The posts float - the bottoms don't touch the ground.  I wanted an air gap between my deck and the house and didn't want to open up the basement ceiling to install the structural components into the basement joist space.  I paid an engineer to approve my design - was fairly minimal like $500.

@FreshCodemonger Would you clarify;; I think you are saying that you have a real post embedded in the ground out in space where the beam is past the house but then where the beam is attached to the house you have floating posts underneath it that are flush to the foundation right underneath it?? How many of those, or how many per foot of beam do you have ? thanks.

The post out in space is ~3' away from the house.  The beam is a PT treated PSL 11.75x5.25 @ 22' long.  I have two nominal 6" pt posts 4' tall that are floating but epoxy bolted in two places vertically to the 8" poured concrete wall.  So a total of 3 supports for the beam.  The 20' psl beam sits 3/4" off the concrete wall ( beam is 5.25 post is 6" ) so that I have an air gap from the house.

You can hypothetically do what you describe, but the challenge is supporting the end against the house properly. You can't simply lag screw it into framing or bolt it to the foundation (even with single ledgers in some cases). Beams must have bottom bearing in many jurisdictions these days.
You'd have to find suitable engineered steel bracketry from the likes of Simpson Strong-Tie and others. You might find it easier to simply use a double joist hanger on the single ledger*.
Whatever you decide, run it by your inspection authority before you commit. Also be wary of falsely "overbuilding" when it really just means wasted lumber. It doesn't make sense to double the ledger beyond what you need for proper support at the building corner. You gain nothing from that.

* Either bend one flange flat and fasten it to the end of the ledger, or extend the ledger 3-4" to give the hanger the necessary mounting area (and prevent splits). The actual cantilever is an inch or so, so I can't imagine an inspector complaining.

I think you are saying that if the wood member is a beam somewhere it has to be treated like a beam everywhere? So that means where I COULD attach a plain old ledger with lags into framing for a BEAM I need to have bottom bearing even where it is up against the house??

I don't think I said that, but it needs to be supported as a beam wherever it acts like one. Id id say that ledgers often cannot be simply screwed to the wall anymore. Approved hardware must be used.
